# Receive duplicate push notification in android device in phonegap build app using pushwoosh plugin

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

My android app is developed using phonegap build. I am integrating pushwoosh plugin for receiving push notifications. In serverside push messages are sending with fcm ($url ='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';) using curl. But in app I am receiving duplicate message. How this happen? Please help me.
The plugin used in congig.xml is

```
<gap:plugin name="pushwoosh-cordova-plugin@7.0.8" source="npm"/>
```

Comment: mam, make sure its not sending request multiple times .. check log ..